# Cordova GUI not loading correctly for iOS 8.1

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ios8.1

I've been asked to provide added functionality for a cordova iOS project that was developed previously. In the simulator the app runs perfectly for OS 7.1 on an device but on the OS 8.1 it doesnt seem to scale correctly and the images aren't loading. I've updated cordova and I'm using Xcode 6.1.1.

This is the target output below:

```
dlopen_preflight(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/MacOS/QuickLook)
dlopen_preflight(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/Mac OS X/QuickLook)
dlopen_preflight(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/MacOSClassic/QuickLook)
dlopen_preflight(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/Mac OS 8/QuickLook)
dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/QuickLook, 0x00000115)
  dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/QuickLook) ==> 0x11c5bd
2015-01-23 13:28:39.577 Daffodil Day[10984:92068] Finished load of: file:///Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FF018458-F8C5-475A-9AEF-D2B2AF99CE53/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/78F811B7-9A6D-4B3A-AC8A-659B66B40DD9/Daffodil%20Day.app/www/index.html
dyld_image_path_containing_address(0x10c9dcf3)
dlopen_preflight(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsCore.framework/MacOS/DataDetectorsCore)
dlopen_preflight(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsCore.framework/Mac OS X/DataDetectorsCore)
dlopen_preflight(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsCore.framework/MacOSClassic/DataDetectorsCore)
dlopen_preflight(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsCore.framework/Mac OS 8/DataDetectorsCore)
dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsCore.framework/DataDetectorsCore, 0x00000115)
  dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsCore.framework/DataDetectorsCore) ==> 0xcd077f81
Daffodil Day(10984,0xb0093000) malloc: protecting edges
Daffodil Day(10984,0xb0093000) malloc: recording malloc and VM allocation stacks to disk using standard recorder
Daffodil Day(10984,0xb0093000) malloc: enabling scribbling to detect mods to free blocks
_dyld_get_image_slide(0x1000)
Daffodil Day(10984,0xb0093000) malloc: purgeable zone does not support guard pages
2015-01-23 13:28:41.564 Daffodil Day[10984:92068] Resetting plugins due to page load.
dlopen(/usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib, 0x00000002)
  dlopen(/usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib) ==> 0x11735c
dlsym(0x11735c, MGCopyAnswer)
dlopen(/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion, 0x00000002)
dyld: loaded: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion
dyld_image_path_containing_address(0x1269a000)
dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion, 0x00000010)
  dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion) ==> 0x262fbf60
  dlopen(/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion) ==> 0x262fbf60
dlopen(/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation, 0x00000002)
  dlopen(/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation) ==> 0x110f84
dlsym(0x11c5bc, QLTypeCopyBestMimeTypeForFileNameAndMimeType)
dlopen(/System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices, 0x00000002)
  dlopen(/System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices) ==> 0x111e48
dlsym(0x111e48, kUTTagClassFilenameExtension)
dlsym(0x111e48, UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag)
dlopen(/System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices, 0x00000002)
  dlopen(/System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices) ==> 0x111e48
dlsym(0x111e48, kUTTagClassMIMEType)
dlsym(0x111e48, UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass)
dlsym(0x111e48, UTTypeCopyDeclaration)
dlsym(0x111e48, kUTTypeConformsToKey)
2015-01-23 13:28:44.814 Daffodil Day[10984:92068] Finished load of: file:///Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FF018458-F8C5-475A-9AEF-D2B2AF99CE53/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/78F811B7-9A6D-4B3A-AC8A-659B66B40DD9/Daffodil%20Day.app/www/startscreen.html
dlopen(/usr/lib/liblangid.dylib, 0x00000005)
  dlopen(/usr/lib/liblangid.dylib) ==> 0x117a3c
dlsym(0x117a3c, langid_identify_withbuf)
dlsym(0x117a3c, langid_languagecode)
2015-01-23 13:28:45.526 Daffodil Day[10984:92068] DEPRECATION NOTICE: The Connection ReachableViaWWAN return value of '2g' is deprecated as of Cordova version 2.6.0 and will be changed to 'cellular' in a future release.
```

This is the code for the footer, the icons are not loading (i.e ) and I think that this might be offsetting the scaling of the screen images.

```
<footer class="bottom_links" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
                <ul>
                    <li><a class="footer_links" href="social.html" rel="external">
                        <div class="icon_a" align="center">&#xf086;</div>
                        </br>
                        <div class="text_a" align="center">Social</div>
                    </a></li>
                    <li><a class="footer_links" href="map.html" rel="external">
                        <div class="icon_a" align="center">&#xf041;</div>
                        </br>
                        <div class="text_a" align="center">Locations</div>
                    </a></li>
                    <li><a class="footer_links" href="volunteer.html"
                        rel="external">
                        <div class="icon_a" align="center">&#xf0c0;</div>
                        </br>
                        <div class="text_a" align="center">Volunteer</div>
                    </a></li>
                    <li><a class="footer_links" href="donate.html" rel="external">
                        <div class="icon_a" align="center">&#xf153;</div>
                        </br>
                        <div class="text_a" align="center">Donate</div>
                    </a></li>
                    <li><a class="footer_links" href="about.html" rel="external">
                        <div class="icon_a" align="center">&#xf05a;</div>
                        </br>
                        <div class="text_a" align="center">About</div>
                    </a></li>
                </ul>
            </footer>
```

Comment: Did you notice the Deprecation notice? What is your question?

Comment: I don't have much experience with cordova so I'm unsure what the deprecation notice means. I'm wondering is there specific updates that would have to be applied to the plugins etc to allow it to render correctly on the OS 8.1 because this is the only operating system that is causing problems. It runs perfectly on all others (OS 7.1, android, Windows)